# IOS Audio won't work after stop idle awhile

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ios6, avaudioplayer

My application worked fine when I play and stop the music at the start of the running but when I later stopped the music and let the application idle for quite some time and clicked the play button, the application didn't output any warning and no music is played even the log output my music is now playing. I have no idea what is the error that leads to this as nothing is wrong. Is it a common behavior in IOS simulator?

This is my audio code just in case.

```
-(void)musicIsPlaying:(id)sender
{
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [sender objectForKey:@"audio"];
    UIButton *btn = [sender objectForKey:@"button"];
    if (btn.selected == TRUE) 
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setSelected:FALSE];    
        if(theAudio.isPlaying == NO)
        {
            [theAudio prepareToPlay];
            [theAudio play];
            NSLog(@"music playing");
        }                                    
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setSelected:TRUE];
        if(theAudio.isPlaying==YES)
        {
            [theAudio stop];
            NSLog(@"music stop playing");
        }        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call method to resume your play when Application becomes active. So, write your code to resume your play in Appdelegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    you need to Declare AVAudioPlayer in Interface

    @interface AudioViewController ()
    {
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
    }
    @end

the use this "theAudio" object in your method(musicIsPlaying)..like 
theAudio = [sender objectForKey:@"audio"];
    Hope..it will work for you...
```